# enable tcp_syncookies even after reboot

Tags: linux, networking

I'm running Scientific Linux 6.1 and would like to set `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1`. I've set that in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and, if I do a `sysctl -p` then `sysctl -q net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` it shows it's properly set.  Sadly, if I reboot the machine, and `sysctl -q` again, it goes back to 0.

I've tried to grep around and see if something else is resetting it to 0 during the boot process but haven't turned up anything.

I've googled and everything points to `sysctl.conf`.

The only thing I can think of is maybe networking isn't up by the time that file gets read but, honestly, I'm a developer and well beyond my natural skills here:)  I'm tempted to just set it directly in `/etc/init.d/network` but then that feels hackish and so, I thought better of it and I'm here in search of the "right" way to do it. Any pointers?

Comment: `sysctl.conf` is the right place to set this, and this works as expected on my CentOS 6 system. Are the other values specified in `sysctl.conf` being set? It seems that this is done by `apply_sysctl()` in `/etc/init.d/network`, so the only other thing I can think of is that this isn't being run for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could just put this code in your /etc/rc.local file:

```
check_syn_cookie=`grep -r net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies /etc/sysctl.conf | grep -v ^#`
[ "$check_syn_cookie" = "" ] && echo "net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

But please make sure that it goes before any exit statements. It should force your net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies to be 1 at startup.